# rpm file to deb Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: rpm

I would like to install .rpm file using alien

```
sudo alien --scripts  /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm

error: incorrect format: unknown tag
mkdir: cannot create directory `oracle-xe-11.2.0': File exists
unable to mkdir oracle-xe-11.2.0:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257
```

Getting the above error.

and then

```
    root@atten2015:~# sudo alien --verbose  --scripts  /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-                                             1.0.x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{NAME} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x8                                             6_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{VERSION} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0                                             .x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{RELEASE} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0                                             .x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{ARCH} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x8                                             6_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{CHANGELOGTEXT} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2                                             .0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{SUMMARY} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0                                             .x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{DESCRIPTION} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0                                             -1.0.x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{COPYRIGHT} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1                                             .0.x86_64.rpm
error: incorrect format: unknown tag
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{PREFIXES} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.                                             0.x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{POSTIN} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.                                             x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{POSTUN} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.                                             x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{PREUN} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x                                             86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qp --queryformat %{PREIN} /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x                                             86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qcp /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
        rpm -qpi /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
        LANG=C rpm -qpl /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
        mkdir oracle-xe-11.2.0
mkdir: cannot create directory `oracle-xe-11.2.0': File exists
unable to mkdir oracle-xe-11.2.0:  at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package.pm line 257
```

Comment: The RPM format has changed since 2010 and that file is from 2014. Use a recent version of alien/Ubuntu and try again.

Comment: `alien` can't run `mkdir oracle-xe-11.2.0`. Remove `rm -r oracle-xe-11.2.0` or rename `mv oracle-xe-11.2.0 oracle-xe-11.2.0.bak` and try again.

Comment: can't understand

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam, remove your `oracle-xe-11.2.0` directory: `rm -r oracle-xe-11.2.0`, run `sudo alien --scripts  /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: I have run this already as said above but got above error.

Comment: Post the ouput of `sudo alien --verbose --scripts /root/Disk1/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: Post the output of `alien --version`

Comment: see above edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26583/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-evgeny-vereshchagin).